# Fastest search in unsorted log file.Is there any method more efficient that linear search?

Tags: c

How to do fastest search in unsorted log file.Is there any method more efficient that linear search?
The log file is in MB.Needed method to perform search in lesser time.

Comment: Can you give some more detail?  What are you searching on?  You could sort the file for better asymptotic performance, but if there is no order you can exploit, then you're unlikely to do much better than a linear search.

Comment: No. It's unsorted so you don't have any idea where it could be, it could be the first line, it could be the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Build an index. But that also takes at least linear time. But without any index and no sorting, how are you going to skip reading all data?

The best trick you can do is string matching algorithms such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt, but that only helps when your search string is long and there are many similar false matches. Doesn't save you any I/O either.

Comment: If you build the index once and use it for many searches, then the amortisized time gets smaller. And such an index could be built and updated incrementally.

Comment: That's right. Just like sorting such things can pay off already after a few queries.